# Jquery treeview and Ajax

Tags: jquery, treeview, tree, jstree, jtree

Im using Jquery tree view for a tree structure on my website..The tree structure is big..so initially 10 nodes are displayed and on each click of the ('+') more nodes are fetched from the db using ajax it is then wrapped in an anchor tag and displayed under the ul > li..My question is when clicking the anchor tag it will redirect to a new page with the initial 10 nodes only (Obviously yes)..anyway to keep this tree structure as is on the new page ?

Any help techie guys ??

This is what im using 
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/

Comment: Thanks all..i managed to achieve what im looking for used cookie functionalities to store the ids of nodes and calling ajax on the load of the page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to prevent your  tag from changing the location of your page so that your treeview works fine, then you have at least 2 ways of doing this:

1. Do not use the a tag if you do not want to link to somewhere else ;).
2. in the href attribute, write: void(0);

Fake hyperlink

There must be much other cleaner ways of doing this, but at least it works fine. I'd be glad to learn the best way though ;)

Comment: Thanks nicholas...but someway i need to use that link. Is there something like session of php in client side ..i mean to store the tree in a session and then just displaying

Comment: Humm, not really sure what you are trying to achieve then. If you need to be able to 1. expand your tree nodes and 2. to use the hyperlink as a real hyperlink, I would suggest that you rework your design as it could be odd for some people to use since they expect a hyperlink to have only one function. So you choose to have it link to something or to expand but not both at the same time.

Comment: When you say "i need to use that link", what do you mean in terms of "usage" of the link? Are you talking about the loading of the sub nodes dynamically thanks to an AJAX request, or something else?
The trick I gave you is simply to prevent the browser from navigating to a new url, that's all. But you can then have your hyperlink do whatever you want in the "onclick" event, like for instance load subnodes, display some kind of waiting message if that is a long process, refresh another webpart in your page etc.